# Best conjugation for memento vivere or viveri

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, conjugation

Memento vivere or viveri, as a complementary phrase (not necessary an opposite) to memento mori?

Answer (score 6):

That would be *Memento vivere*, which is the exact same construction as *Memento mori*, except with “live” instead of “die.” And in any event we can categorically rule out *viveri* because that word does not even exist in the Latin language.

The passive form of *vivere* would be *vivi* (it's third, not second conjugation), but the situation does not call for a passive form – you are supposed to remember to live, not to be lived. (Ah, but, you say, then why is *mori* passive? That's because it's a [deponent verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deponent_verb),
which means it's always passive, but the meaning is “die” – and not “to be died” – nonetheless.)